# The number of Darboux functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, set-theory, cardinals

What is the number of real-valued functions of a real variable that have the Darboux property? I know it's at least continuum, because it's a broader class than continuous functions, whose number is continuum; but does it go any further?

Comment: Not a proof, but I’d expect it to be more: unless I’m mistaken (I can very well be), we can find a subset $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ with empty interior which isn’t co-countable and a function $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that the image of $U \cap I$ for any interval $I$ is $\mathbb{R}$. Then any extension of $f$ does the job (and there are $2^\mathbb{R}$ of them).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Let $I_1,I_2,I_3,\dots$ be an enumeration of the intervals with rational endpoints. Choose pairwise disjoint Cantor sets $C_n\subset I_n$. (This is possible since $C_1\cup C_2\cup\cdots\cup C_{n-1}$ is nowhere dense.) For each $n\in\mathbb N$ define a bijection $f_n:C_n\to\mathbb R$.

If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is such that $f\supseteq\bigcup_{n=2}^\infty f_n$ then $f$ has the Darboux property. The number of such functions $f$ is $2^\mathfrak c$ since $f$ may take arbitrary values on $C_1$.

More generally, given any function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ which takes all real values in every interval, we can modify it arbitrarily on a nowhere dense set, and the resulting function will have he same property.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent subset with cardinality that of $\mathbb{R}$. As $\mathbb{R}$ is equipotent to $\mathbb{R}^2$, there is a partition $X=\cup_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}}{X_{\alpha}}$ with each $X_{\alpha}$ being in bijection with $\mathbb{R}$.

In particular, by rescaling some vectors in $X_{\alpha}$, we can make sure that every empty bounded open interval with rational endpoints contains some element in $X_{\alpha}$ – thus every nonempty open interval contains points of $X_{\alpha}$.

Now consider any function $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(X_{\alpha})=\{\alpha\}$. There are $2^{\mathbb{R}}$ possibilities for $f$ (because there are no constraints on $2X$ and $2X$ is in bijection with $\mathbb{R}$), but by the above construction $f(I)=\mathbb{R}$ for any open interval $I$, so $f$ is Darboux.

Comment: Is there an easy example of such a $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent subset $X$?

Comment: I don’t know any for sure. We may need choice to find one, but it’s also possible that under weaker versions of  choice, we can make an “explicit” construction. Note though that what we really need is a set of representatives for $\mathbb{R}^{\times}/\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$, linear independence doesn’t really come into play. Maybe the $x_{\alpha}=\sum_{i \geq 1}{2^{-\lfloor \alpha^{i}\rfloor}}$ for $\alpha >2$ could fit the bill.